# Logic error with C# if statement but I'm unsure why

Tags: c#, logic-error

I am just starting to learn C# in college and I was tasked with making a console program that acts as a maths quiz, with my if statements it only outputs correct even if the user inputs an incorrect answer, I can't figure out why, I've looked at multiple websites but everything seems to be fine with the code? I was hoping someone here with more experience would be able to help.

Below is the code but I can't figure out what's wrong with it, like I said before I looked over multiple websites and my code seems to be in line with what they were doing, my teacher also had a glance at it but couldn't see any faults

```cs
// we need to make a maths quiz..

using System;

namespace MathsQuiz
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static Random GetRandom()
        {  
            return new Random(); 
        }
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //this is where the random numbers are generated
           Random random = GetRandom();
            int num1 = random.Next(1, 100);
            int num2 = random.Next(1, 100);

            int answer = num1 + num2;

            /*this shows the user the question using
            the randomly generated numbers*/
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the maths quiz!\nWe still start with addition,\n add these following numbers\n" + num1 + "+" + num2 + "=   ?");


            int UserAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            //checks if the users answer is correct

            if (Convert.ToBoolean(UserAnswer = answer))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
            }
            else if (Convert.ToBoolean(UserAnswer != answer))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint 1: what do you believe `UserAnswer = answer` does? Hint 2: did you *expect* to need to use `Convert.ToBoolean`? You shouldn't...

Comment: You don't need the `Convert.ToBoolean()` since `==` or ``!=` explicit cast to a boolean. Furthermore, you are using `=` right now for comparing two values. Always use `==` for comparision.

Comment: `=` isn't an equality operator. BTW, what if the user enters `Banana`? Also, an answer can only ever be correct or incorrect. There isn't a third option here, so no need for `else if...`, a simple `else` will do.

Comment: The issue was within the Convert bit, removing Convert.ToBoolean() and adding another = so it was "==" fixed the issue. Thank you to Jon Skeet, Maik Hasler and Zohar Peled for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As some comments already state:

- no need for the Convert.ToBoolean
- '=' is not a logical comparison operator
- as it can be either 'true' or 'false' -> no need for two ifs at all
- recommend to have lower case namings for variables

So adjust your code to look like this:

```
if (userAnswer == answer) 
{ /* correct answer */ 
} 
else 
{ /* incorrect answer */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the equals operator `==`. The result of an assignment expression is the assigned value. This means that `UserAnswer = answer` replaces the `UserAnswer` by `answer`. This results in whatever integer value `answer` is and not in `true` or `false`.

The value of `answer` is then converted to a Boolean which is independent of the the user's answer.

The result of a comparison with `==` or `!=` or any other comparison operator like `>` is a Boolean, so no explicit type conversion is required.

The if statement should  be like this instead:

```cs
if (UserAnswer == answer) ...
```

Another point is that the `if` statement processes the `true` case and the `else` statement the `false` case. I.e., `else` automatically handles the "Incorrect" case. No further `if` is required.

```cs
if (UserAnswer == answer)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect.");
}
```